# Bandwidth of low pass filter: measured with the cut-off frequency?

Tags: filter, cutoff-frequency

I have the following Sallen & Key lowpass filter:

$$T(s)=\frac{\frac{1}{R_1R_2C_1C_2}}{s^2+(\frac{1}{C_1R_1}+\frac{1}{C_1R_2})s+\frac{1}{R_1R_2C_1C_2}}$$

The parameters values are

- \$R_1=10 k\Omega\$
- \$R_2=10 k\Omega\$
- \$C_1=150 nF\$
- \$C_2=1.65 nF\$

On Mathematica I simulated the magnitude response:

[image]

Now I need to find an expression for the bandwidth of the filter. I know that the bandwidth of a low-pass filter corresponds to the cut-off frequency.

- How do I calculate the bandwidth in Mathematica?
- Is the cut-off frequency measured at -3 dB of the low-pass gain, or the maximum of the filter? I know this spike I see is expected as Q>1.

Comment: At the 3dB bandwidth, the magnitude is 3 dB below the value at DC.

Comment: Granger, the cutoff frequency is just what you'd calculate from \$\omega_{_0}\$. (Close to the peak, I think.) Your Q is about 4.77 (easily calculated from the capacitors' geometric mean and ratio.) If you arrange the capacitor values to instead use the \$\sqrt{2}\$ as their geometric ratios (or here, just make C1 twice C2 while keeping the product of C1 and C2 constant), then you'd have a very nice -3 db point right at where your peak is currently at. Do you want more explanation? Or is that enough?

Comment: Try plotting, using \$C_1=22.25\:\text{nF}\$ and \$C_2=11.125\:\text{nF}\$ (2nd order Butterworth solution.) Observe the -3.0103 dB point on the Bode plot. The cutoff frequency is always \$\omega_{_0}\$ and isn't dependent upon the -3.0103 dB point. See [this site](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPstool.php) and plug in your values and it will compute similar cutoff frequency for your case and the above Butterworth case despite the vast difference in behavior near the cutoff frequency. Finally, how do you define bandwidth in the case of a low-pass filter given how many types exist? I'm curious.